# how many POUCHDB database can I host in 1 phonegap application

Tags: cordova, pouchdb

Hi I have 1 phonegap app, and I know the max size of the database is 50 mb (more or less), I know I can have more than one database per phonegap app, the question is can I have something like 5 databases to the max size? in that case I will have 5 databases 50 mb each, 250 mb in total. will my phonegap app be able to to host the 5 databases?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the platform. Android and iOS have very different (and very subtle) ways of calculating how much space you are allowed to store. It will also depend on whether you are using the SQLite Plugin or not.

Currently the best source of information is this: http://pouchdb.com/faq.html#data_limits

In any case, if your question is whether 5 databases with 50 MB each will function differently than 1 database with 250 MB, the surprising answer is: **yes**. I have actually seen this in practice when testing PouchDB in Safari, and I cannot explain why, but [it does seem to influence](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/2737) how much you are allowed to store.

Really the only way to know for sure is to test on a real device.